# Кнопки таймера Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть код с двумя кнопками, которые запускают таймер. Как мне сделать, чтобы при активации одного таймера, кнопка с другим таймером не работала?

```
    mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnFragment1);
    mTimer = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtFragment1);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new CountDownTimer(80000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    mTimer.setText("It left:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    mTimer.setText("Care!!!");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
    mButton2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnFragment2);
    mTimer2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtFragment2);
    mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new CountDownTimer(80000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    mTimer2.setText("It left:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    mTimer2.setText("Care!!!");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `setOnClickListener` каждой кнопки делайте неактивной другую:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mButton2.setClickable(false); //или mButton2.setEnabled(false);
            ...
        }
    });

mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mButton.setClickable(false); //или mButton.setEnabled(false);
            ...
        }
    });
```

Ну а после остановки (или зависит от Вашей реализации), делайте ее активной. Дабы не проверять, сразу обе кнопки можете:

```
mButton.setClickable(true);  //или mButton.setEnabled(true);
mButton2.setClickable(true); //или mButton2.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Cделайте её некликабельной

```
button.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: а как задать, чтобы она была некликабельна тогда, когда я нажал на другой таймер?